# Consume preference click event

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I am facing a problem while trying to consume click event of a preference. There's a preference, and on clicking it, I open a sub screen with different preference categories. What I want to achieve is that if a certain condition is false, a toast should popup, and the sub screen shouldn't open. In case it's true, it should work normally and open the sub screen. For this, I tried the following piece of code :

```
    mPref = (Preference) findPreference("abc");
    mPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (!condition) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;    // Consume click event.
    }
    return false;
}
```

The relevant part of xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="abc"
    android:summary="@string/string_turn_on"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:title="@string/string_turn_on">

     <PreferenceCategory 
         android:key="asa"
         android:title="a" >
        <com.example.gaurav.CustomPref
            android:defaultValue="0"
            android:key="st"
            android:dependency="e"
            android:showDefault="true"
            android:summary="summary"
            android:title="t" />
        <com.example.gaurav.CustomPref
            android:defaultValue="0"
            android:key="st"
            android:dependency="e"
            android:showDefault="true"
            android:summary="so"
            android:title="so" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="other" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="e"
            android:title="eb" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

 </PreferenceScreen>
```

I have changed the strings etc, but I don't think they cause this error, so it won't matter. It's the preference with key "abc" which launches a sub screen which I want to prevent from launching. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this line in the `onCreate` method

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

edit:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
   if (condition) {
      return true;    // Consume click event.
   }
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I guess you didn't get my question properly. The preference is shown in settings screen, so this line is already there. The problem is that I want to consume the click event for the preference (which launches another screen i.e. CustomPref) in case a certain condition holds false. When I try above code, the toast is shown, but the sub-screen also opens. I doubt this is possible, so I ended up asking here.

Comment: To be honest I have never done something like that but I would try moving the Toast outside the if block and see if it pops up in this case

Comment: Hi Haint, I know it's a bit different kind of thing, that's why I asked it here. Regarding your suggestions, toast is not the problem, it shows even when it's inside the if block. Problem is blocking the click for preference, when the condition is false.

Comment: I didn't say that the Toast was the problem, I mean you could try changing your if condition a little bit as shown in my editted answer, notice I changed `condition==true` as opposed to `condition==false` in your original code

Comment: This way you could tell your app to open the sub preference when the condition is true, another way of saying don't open if condition is false

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work either. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this problem and I **solved it** creating a custom Preference class which overrides `onClick` event and `setOnPreferenceClickListener`
This is the custom class:

```java
public class InterceptableEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference {

    private OnPreferenceClickListener customOnPreferenceClickListener;

    public InterceptableEditTextPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public InterceptableEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public InterceptableEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClick() {

        if (customOnPreferenceClickListener != null) {
            boolean handled = customOnPreferenceClickListener.onPreferenceClick(this);
            if (handled) {
                return;
            }
        }

        super.onClick();

    }

    @Override
    public void setOnPreferenceClickListener(OnPreferenceClickListener onPreferenceClickListener) {
        customOnPreferenceClickListener = onPreferenceClickListener;
    }
}
```

This way when you set the listener, the returned value is taken into account to continue with the default click behaviour (show the dialog) or not:

```java
editTextPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(preference -> {

    if(someCondition) {
         return true; // This prevent the PreferenceDialog to appear
         // To manually show the dialog you can call: 
         // getPreferenceManager().showDialog(preference);
    }

    return false;
});
```

---

### Explanation

The previous "workaround" should be the default behaviour but for some reason, analyzing the SDK `Preference` class we find this:

[image: preference onClick() event]

Which means `onClick()` is always called (if the preference is enabled and selectable) and not depend on the boolean value returned by `mOnClickListener.onPreferenceClick`